# SQLITE error Unable to open file

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to create a database for an app in the data directory. I tried to use

```
try{
        String path = "/data/data/"+context+"/database/Einkaufsliste.sqlite";
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path,null);
    }
```

But I get always the following exception:
unable to open database file

Logcat gives the following result:

> 04-10 19:55:09.387: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(554):
>   sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/at.einkaufsliste/database/Einkaufsliste.sqlite",
>   &handle, 6, NULL) failed 04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):
>   Failed to open the database. closing it. 04-10 19:55:09.527:
>   E/SQLiteDatabase(554):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to
>   open database file 04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method) 04-10
>   19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
>   04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
>   04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:962)
>   04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1043)
>   04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   at.einkaufsliste.Database.createOrOpen(Database.java:33) 04-10
>   19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):  at
>   at.einkaufsliste.Database.(Database.java:23) 04-10 19:55:09.527:
>   E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   at.einkaufsliste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50) 04-10
>   19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 04-10
>   19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>   04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 04-10
>   19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-10
>   19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-10 19:55:09.527:
>   E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 04-10
>   19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-10
>   19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-10 19:55:09.527:
>   E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   04-10 19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 04-10
>   19:55:09.527: E/SQLiteDatabase(554):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I set the permission EXTERNAL Storage and the group permisson.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<permission-group android:name="android.permission-group.STORAGE"></permission-group>
```

What is wrong with this usage?

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with this usage?

**NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**. `/data/data` is wrong for many users. [Use `getDatabasePath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) to get the location where a database file should go on internal storage. This will also fix your problems with using string concatenation to build a path.

That would give you:

```
try {
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(getDatabasePath("Einkaufsliste.sqlite"), null);
}
```

assuming that this code is called from a method in a subclass of `Context`. Otherwise, you will need to arrange to call `getDatabasePath()` on a `Context`.

> I set the permission EXTERNAL Storage

If by this you mean that you have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, that does not matter here, as you are not putting the database on external storage

> and the group permisson

I have no idea what that means, sorry.

Also, please consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, to be able to handle database schema changes over time.

Comment: If I use `database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(context.getDatabasePath("Einkaufsliste.sqlite"),null);` then I still get the same result.

Comment: @IrgendwPointer: Try a full uninstall and reinstall of your app, in case permissions on your internal storage got messed up. Otherwise, I do not know why this would not work.